# Local copy has greater version number than fresh check out CVS copy

Tags: cvs, wincvs

My local copy version number is showing 1.6 when I go to the graph. But when I check out a fresh copy the it shows version number 1.3. What could be the reasons?

Comment: Are you checking out a branch/tag?

Comment: @BurhanAli: i am not using SVN. i am talking about CVS(winCVS).

Comment: CVS also has branches and tags.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone ran something like `cvs admin -o 1.3::` in the workspace.

```
cvs --help admin
...
        -o range   Delete (outdate) specified range of revisions:
           rev1:rev2   Between rev1 and rev2, including rev1 and rev2.
           rev1::rev2  Between rev1 and rev2, excluding rev1 and rev2.
           rev:        rev and following revisions on the same branch.
           rev::       After rev on the same branch.
           :rev        rev and previous revisions on the same branch.
           ::rev       Before rev on the same branch.
           rev         Just rev.
...
```

`cvs admin -o` does all sorts of evil, including making it possible for a workspace to be damaged to create revision issues such as this.  This command can remove revisions from the repository without properly updating a workspace revision metadata in the CVS/Entries file.